# Lemma I.13.19 on Kunen's set theory

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I'm not even sure how to approach this problem. Kunen defined for arbitary sets $B$ and cardinals $\theta$, 
$$ [B]^\theta = \{ x \subseteq B : |x| = \theta \} $$
$$ [B]^{< \theta} = \{ x \subseteq B : |x| \leq \theta \} $$
And the problem (working in ZFC without foundation) I'm stuck on is the second part of lemma I.13.19: if $B$ is infinite and $\aleph_{0} \leq \theta \leq |B|$, then
$$ |[B]^\theta | = |B|^\theta $$
And
$$ |[B]^{< \theta} | = |B|^{< \theta} $$
Here $B^A$ is the cardinal exponentiation, and $B^{< A} = | \{ f: C \to B : C$ is an ordinal and $C < A\}|$
I've only managed to show the trivial inequalities like $|[B]^\theta | \leq |B|^\theta$. I'm sure the proof is probably pretty simple, but I'm pretty clueless about what I should do next, any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: What was your proof for the statement that you were able to prove?

Comment: You might first try the case $\theta=|B|=\aleph_0$.

Comment: Which book is that? I have Kunen, _Set Theory: An Introduction to Independence Proofs_ (Elsevier, 1980), and there chapter I §13 doesn't contain anything numbered higher than 13.2.

Comment: @Henning Makholm it's his 2013 set theory book, I think he has a related exercise at the end of his section on cardinal arithmetic from his foundations of mathematics book

Comment: @Michael McGovern if you are talking about the inequality, I figired I could just make an injection from subsets of size $\theta$ to some bijection from that set to $\theta$, if you are talking about the first half of the lemma, it was to show that $| [B]^n| =|[B]^{< \omega}| = |B|$ I figured $| [B]^n| = |B×(B-1)×...×(B-n+1)| = |B|$ where $(B-k)$ is just B with k less elements. And $|[B]^{< \omega}|$ is just $\omega$ blocks of things of cardinality $|B|$, so its cardinality must be $\omega \cdot |B|$

Comment: I am pretty sure $[B]^{< \theta}$ should be all the subsets of $B$ of cardinality *strictly* less than $\theta$ (your third line says "less then or equal to").